# Lan emulator over the internet

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, emulation, p2p

i'm new to this programming with sockets.

Can anyone tell me what do I need to do to make a LAN emulator, so I can connect to a server through its address and port which will simulate a LAN connection between us?

I am going to use java for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server would need to create a java.net.ServerSocket and give it a port to listen on

The client would need to create a java.net.Socket and give it the server's address and port to connect to.

Use the ServerSocket's accept() method to create the handshake, and do what you want with the connection from there.

Use this to get you started: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between lan connections and non-lan (wan) connections in most protocols.

The only relevant cases are multi-/broad-/anycasts (which usually do not work over internet).